# Taking signs out of columns of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My textbook presents the following matrix and asks to find its determinant:

$$d=\left|\begin{array} --1&1&-2\\-1&-1&-4\\-1&1&-7\end{array}\right|$$

And then says that it takes the negative sign from the first column and the negative sign from the third column so that the matrix becomes:

$$d=\left|\begin{array}11&1&2\\1&-1&4\\1&1&7\end{array}\right|$$

I understand that it is possible to multiply any row by -$1$, but if I were to multiply every row by $-1$ then the second column would have the signs inverted. Any hints on how this is possible to take the negative signs out of the matrix?

Comment: The determinant is also linear in every column, so you can just multiply the first and the third column with $-1$.

Comment: Multiplying a column (row) by $c\neq 0$ gives $c \det A.$ If you multiply two columns by $(-1),$ the determinant doesn't change. If you multiplied all columns of this $3\times 3$ matrix by $(-1)$ you would get $- \det A.$

Comment: @Cesare I think there is a typo in your edit. Didn't you mean to write the $(1,1)$ entry after taking negative signs as $-1$ instead of $1$

Comment: @ab123 correct, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than premultiplying the matrix, try post multiplying the matrix by $diag(-1, 1, -1)$ to achieve that result.

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1&-2\\-1&-1&-4\\-1&1&-7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0&0 \\ 0&1&0\\0&0& - 1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1&1&2\\1&-1&4\\1&1&7\end{bmatrix}$$

In terms of determinant, we can perform elementary column operations. You can view it as taking transpose (transpose doesn't change the determiant), perform row operations, then taking transpose back again.

Answer (score 2):

Since $det(A^T) = det (A)$, you can apply operations to columns in just the same way as you apply them to rows, so just multiply first and third columns by $-1$